# Running padrinorb after installing says "Could not find padrino-core"

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

**EDIT:**
False alarm.

I was able to resolve the issue. Apparently I was to `sudo` happy and that broke the install of the gem.
I had to `gem uninstall padrino`, then `gem install padrino`.

Now it works flawlessly.
BTW, padrinorb is shaping up to be a nice balance between Sinatra and Rails.

// *original post below:*

Not sure what I did wrong.
I'm trying to test out [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com), however I'm running into an issue straight away.

I'm following the steps starting with `sudo gem install padrino` adding sudo for good measure.
Then following along I did `padrino g project myapp -d datamapper -b` as their site states.

The problem is that it returns an error, so I decided to just run `padrino` as is with no args.
Error as well (it's long):

```
$ padrino
/Users/viper1092/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find padrino-core (>= 0) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.9, RedCloth-4.2.8, actionmailer-3.2.3, actionpack-3.2.3, activemodel-3.2.3, activerecord-3.2.3, activeresource-3.2.3, activesupport-3.2.3, addressable-2.2.7, albino-1.3.3, arel-3.0.2, blankslate-2.1.2.4, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.1.3, bundler-1.0.22, chunky_png-1.2.5, chunky_png-1.2.1, classifier-1.3.3, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.1, compass-0.12.1, compass-0.11.5, crack-0.1.8, daemons-1.1.3, directory_watcher-1.4.1, directory_watcher-1.4.0, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-0.12.10, execjs-1.3.0, faraday-0.7.6, fast-stemmer-1.0.1, fast-stemmer-1.0.0, ffi-1.0.11, ffi-1.0.9, fssm-0.2.9, fssm-0.2.7, haml-3.1.4, haml-3.1.2, heroku-2.24.1, heroku-2.20.1, hike-1.2.1, httparty-0.7.8, i18n-0.6.0, jekyll-0.11.2, jekyll-0.11.0, journey-1.0.3, jquery-rails-2.0.2, json-1.6.6, json-1.5.4, koala-1.3.0, kramdown-0.13.5, kramdown-0.13.3, launchy-2.1.0, launchy-2.0.5, liquid-2.3.0, liquid-2.2.2, mail-2.4.4, maruku-0.6.0, mime-types-1.18, mime-types-1.17.2, multi_json-1.2.0, multi_json-1.0.3, multipart-post-1.1.5, netrc-0.7.1, polyglot-0.3.3, posix-spawn-0.3.6, pygments.rb-0.2.11, pygments.rb-0.1.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-1.3.2, rack-cache-1.2, rack-protection-1.2.0, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.3, railties-3.2.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rake-0.9.2, rb-fsevent-0.9.1, rb-fsevent-0.4.3.1, rdiscount-1.6.8, rdoc-3.12, rest-client-1.6.7, rubypants-0.2.0, rubypython-0.5.3, rubypython-0.5.1, rubyzip-0.9.7, rubyzip-0.9.6.1, sass-3.1.15, sass-3.1.5, sass-rails-3.2.5, sinatra-1.3.2, sinatra-1.2.6, sprockets-2.1.2, sqlite3-1.3.5, stringex-1.3.2, stringex-1.3.0, syntax-1.0.0, term-ansicolor-1.0.7, thin-1.2.11, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, tilt-1.3.2, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.33, uglifier-1.2.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/viper1092/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/viper1092/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /Users/viper1092/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/padrino:18:in `<main>'
```

Then if I take a look at `gem list`:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

polyglot (0.3.3)
posix-spawn (0.3.6)
pygments.rb (0.2.11, 0.1.3)
```

Those are the only "p"s I have.

When I ran `sudo gem install padrino` initially:

```
Successfully installed padrino-mailer-0.10.6
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.3
Successfully installed padrino-gen-0.10.6
Successfully installed padrino-cache-0.10.6
Successfully installed padrino-admin-0.10.6
Successfully installed padrino-0.10.6
21 gems installed
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.3 running RVM 1.10.2 with ruby 1.9.2 selected.

I've tried just gemming Padrino 3 times as `gem install padrino` with no `sudo` just for fun and it reports that it installs, but `padrino` (with or without args) fails with same error. Again, running `gem list` does not mention `padrino` or `padrino-core`.

Any advice?
(I have the full verbosity and it's quite lengthy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Apparently I was to `sudo` happy and that broke the install of the gem.
I had to `gem uninstall padrino`, then `gem install padrino`.
Now it works flawlessly.

I suppose `sudo` installing changes some system-wide /usr deal, idk.
Thanks if you looked over my question.

BTW, padrinorb is shaping up to be a nice balance between Sinatra and Rails.